# What would be a good shader for Linux?

Tags: linux, 3d

I need to draw some diagrams for a printed book. They're fairly simple 3D models (cube houses with cutouts for doors and windows), so Blender should be able to take care of it.

The main problem with Blender is that the result is photo-realistic, which is great for a movie or a high-res image, but would come out looking quite bad on a Black and white physical book. In addition, I feel that Blender is quite an overkill for this. My 3D model is simplistic, and I'd rather not fiddle with textures and lighting. A simple shader (or even better - just the visible outline) would be enough.

What would be a good program for this? I'm on Linux, for the record.